# Manage stdout and stdin in ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

A short ipython notebook cell:

```
%%bash    
read value
5
echo "Value: $value"
```

The output for this cell is `Value: 5`
Is possible to introduce the value interactively using the ipython notebook?

If now I try to run this:

```
%%bash
ssh user@host pwd
```

since is the first time trying to connect to `host`, ssh launches the question:

`Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`

But this question is printed in the shell where I started the ipython notebook, and not in the notebook itself. And here I can write the answer in the shell.

Would be possible to display the output and also introduce my answer through the notebook web interface?

Comment: No, at present you can't interact with subprocesses from the notebook. There's an issue open, but it's not an easy thing to resolve: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/514

Answer (score 0):

This is a frustrating aspect of the notebook, but there's a (now merged) [pull request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3089) to provide the ability to do interactive stdin within the notebook.  To make use of this you'd have to install the `master` branch I believe.

Comment: You can use Python's `input()` / `raw_input()` function to request input, but it doesn't know when the subprocess is waiting for input, so it won't prompt you in this case.

Comment: In IPython 0.13.1 at least, an exception is thrown if you try to call `raw_input()` when using the notebook frontend since it's not supported.

Comment: If you upgrade to IPython 1.x, `raw_input()` will work in the notebook. But it's only the Python call, not reading stdin in general.